# Is writing business logic on client side a security Issue

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase as an application backend for both Android and Ios Clients. My question is, Will there be any security breach if we write business logic on the client side, and what will be the other issues while writing Business logic on the client side with respect to firebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For applications where security is a high priority, you should always assume that an attacker can compromise the code on the client, since the attacker may be able to manipulate the device any way they want.  Because of this, app developers may choose to push critical logic to [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) in order to retain security.

I gave a [talk at I/O 2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eWj6dxfN63g) about this, but in the context of game development, where I assume that attackers may compromise game logic.  The critical game logic lives in Cloud Functions where it can't be compromised by client-side attacks.